# After upload to server, all numbers outputed json is string

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5.13.

I succesfully tested everything on my loclahost. I now uploaded to server.

I did an export from phpMyAdmin with default settings in my localhost (XAMPP, Windows 10), then did a import on remote phpMyAdmin with default settings.

When hit the remote host, it is now giving all fields that I setup in my migrations like this:

```
$table->integer('extension_id')->unsigned();
```

as a string, which is so weird, becuase when on localhost, it is giving as a number.

In the data below, please notice, that in localhost, `displayname_id` and `extensions_id` values are not wrapped with quotes. However `id` is not, which i don't understand, it is also unsigned. My goal is to make even `id` column be string (or if not possible, then make the `*_id` back to number).

Here it is from remote:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Stencil",
        "kind": "cws",
        "created_at": "2017-11-11 00:26:52",
        "updated_at": "2017-11-11 00:26:52",
        "thumbs_count": "1",
        "thumbs_yes_count": "0",
        "latest_comment": {
            "id": 1,
            "body": "huh?",
            "displayname_id": "1",
            "extension_id": "2",
            "created_at": "2017-11-11 00:26:56",
            "updated_at": "2017-11-11 00:26:56"
        }
    }
]
```

Here it is from localhost:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Stencil",
        "kind": "cws",
        "created_at": "2017-11-11 00:26:52",
        "updated_at": "2017-11-11 00:26:52",
        "thumbs_count": "1",
        "thumbs_yes_count": "0",
        "latest_comment": {
            "id": 1,
            "body": "huh?",
            "displayname_id": 1,
            "extension_id": 2,
            "created_at": "2017-11-11 00:26:56",
            "updated_at": "2017-11-11 00:26:56"
        }
    }
]
```

Here is screesnhots of my phpMyAdmin's:

My remote phpMyAdmin is this - [image]

And my local is this - [image]

Here is a screenshot of the table structure, please notice that `id` column's are also unsigned, however they are not being `json_encode`'ed into string.

[image]

Here is export screenshot: https://screenshots.firefoxusercontent.com/images/51d1e47f-fe78-4cdc-8de4-b113d4b576a9.png

Here is import screenshot: https://screenshots.firefoxusercontent.com/images/ff112f86-1c1c-4554-b03c-4b15307c042a.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is your MySQL client driver. Your local machine is using the MySQL Native Driver (`mysqlnd`), whereas your remote server is using the MySQL Client Library (`libmysql`).

The native driver (`mysqlnd`) will treat all integers from the database as integers in PHP. However, the client library (`libmysql`) will treat all fields as strings in PHP.

The reason that the `id` field shows up as an integer on both servers is because of some Laravel magic. Laravel uses the model's `$casts` property to cast specific fields to specific types when accessed. If your `$incrementing` property on your model is `true` (which it is by default), Laravel automatically adds the primary key field (default `id`) to the `$casts` property with the type defined by the `$keyType` property (default `int`). Because of this, whenever you access the `id` field, it will be a PHP integer.

If you want the integer fields to be treated as integers, you could install the MySQL Native Driver (`mysqlnd`) on your remote server.

If that is not an option, or not desirable, you can specify that those fields be treated as integers using the `$casts` property:

```
protected $casts = [
    'displayname_id' => 'int',
    'extension_id' => 'int',
];
```

Now those two fields will be treated as integers regardless of the MySQL driver used.

If you wanted the `id` to be treated as a string, you have a couple options.

First, you could change the `$keyType` value to `string`, but that may have unintended consequences. For example, the `relationHasIncrementingId` on the `BelongsTo` class checks if the key is incrementing and if the key type is `int`, so this method will return false if you change the `$keyType` to `string`.

Second, you could directly add `'id' => 'string'` to your `$casts` array, as the `$casts` value takes priority over the `$keyType` value when accessing the attribute. This would be safer and more semantically correct than changing the `$keyType` value.

And third, if you wanted the `id` to be treated as a string only for JSON conversions, you could override the `jsonSerialize()` method on your model.

```
public function jsonSerialize()
{
    $data = parent::jsonSerialize();

    if (isset($data[$this->primaryKey])) {
        $data[$this->primaryKey] = $this->castAttribute('string', $data[$this->primaryKey]);
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you sir soooo much this was driving me nuts. Your solution looks like a solution. I will try to implement and update you how it goes. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: Wow this is really exactly what I was looking for, I was refreshing here and trying weird stuff and banging my head on a wall for the last couple hours haha. Is there anyway to just have `json_encode` print all `id` and `*_id` fields as numbers in Laravel?

Comment: Wow this was impacting `boolean` values as well, the boolean was turned into "1" or "0" on my remote, `libmsql` wow! `$casts` to `"boolean"` saved the day. Thank you sir! If you know of anyway to get the `id` as string in only `json_encode` (without changing `$keyType`) that would be superior! :) Also I didn't understand what i means to change `$keyType`, do you mean in the model I can just stick in `protected $casts = ['id'=>'string']`? Excuse this please I'm only a couple months into Laravel/backend.

Comment: @Blagoh `$keyType` is another property on the model. So, for the id, you wouldn't change the `$casts` property, you would add `protected $keyType = 'string';` to your model. If you just want to affect the json output, you can override the `jsonSerialize()` method on the model to something like this: `public function jsonSerialize()
{
 $data = parent::jsonSerialize();
 
 if (isset($data[$this->primaryKey])) {
  $data[$this->primaryKey] = $this->castAttribute('string', $data[$this->primaryKey]);
 }
 
 return $data;
}`

Comment: @Blagoh, actually, the `$casts` property takes priority over the `$keyType` setting, so you could leave `$keyType` alone, and add `'id' => 'string'` to your `$casts` property, and that should work just fine. No need to override the `jsonSerialize` method that way.

Comment: Wow this is so ultra ultra cool! Thank you sir! Would puting `'id' => 'string'` in casts also have the possible uninteded side effects of breaking things like the `BelongsTo` relationship? Would it be safter for the jsonSerialize! That json searilize is a super cool thing I had no idea about. Should I create a seperate question so you can post solution there and I can accept that? :) Thanks sir so much I really learned an absolute ton here!

Comment: Thank you. Starred.

Comment: @Blagoh I have updated my answer to make your options a little easier to read. Using the `$casts` property would be safer than changing the `$keyType` value, since your key really is an integer, you just want to cast it to a string when you access it. Overriding the `jsonSerialize()` method would be even safer if you really only want it treated as a string when you json_encode your model.

Comment: Thanks @Tpojka for helping me up vote a superior answer given by Patricus! :)

Comment: Hi there @patricus - is it possible to change my server to not use `libmysql` and instead use `mysqlnd`? I went to "Select PHP Version" in cPanel but i saw "mysqlnd" was already checked - https://screenshots.firefoxusercontent.com/images/dedb6179-1744-4de8-9acf-59b5c9fa9bbc.png - i could not find a way to make it not use "libmysql".

Comment: @Blagoh I would say to enable the `nd_pdo_mysql` driver and disable the `pdo_mysql` driver.

Comment: Thanks @patricus I will test it out next weekend and report back how it goes :)

Answer (score 1):

For Sure this problem is coming from your database OR an old version of php < 5.2.9

But you can try to pass `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` option to your `json_encode` and you are done, it will turn strings representing numbers automatically into numbers:

**Native PHP solution:**

```
echo json_encode($a, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Online [Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cc5f0c983b471f2f50c789f71f2ea026a7944a50)

**Laravel solution:**

```
return response()->json($a, 200, [], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this @Younel, I actually liked the strings, its really perfect because I consume it in javascript where the id's become key's of objects, and keys can only be strings. I was hoping to understand what is causing this, and actually apply it to the `id` column as well.

Comment: My PHP is 7.1, it was 5.6, i am getting same problem on both.

Comment: @Blagoh I'm glad it helps, I think the problem is related to mysql, maybe it casting everything into strings, which mysql you're working with ?

Comment: Thanks sir, checking right now. It would be nice if i could get it to cast `id` field.

Comment: Thanks @Younel - I want to but then others won't look. It's not a solution for me yet :( I was hoping to not modify Laravel but find the database issue and use it as a feature on the `id` column. :( My remote phpMyAdmin is this - https://screenshots.firefoxusercontent.com/images/0aca3f6c-d4e5-44e0-a846-7e7e175169f6.png and my local is this - https://screenshots.firefoxusercontent.com/images/026f4c5e-73e3-46f6-937b-fbfd8d6dd2a0.png

Comment: Wow on further look it seems ALL numbers EXCEPT `id` column are strings, wow so weird, I wonder what is causing that. I don't mind it, if I can just get the `id` to also be string.